# Window Procedure Not Being Called By Message Handler

Tags: c++, oop, winapi, wrapper

I am writing a Windows Api wrapper and I have run into a problem. I am abstracting the Window Procedure (WndProc) and wrote a static MsgHandler which would call the WndProc of my WinHandler class. Here is the code:

```
LRESULT CALLBACK WinHandle::MsgHandler(HWND hwnd,UINT msg,WPARAM wParam,LPARAM lParam)
{
    WinHandle* wnd = 0;

    if (msg == WM_NCCREATE)
    {
        ::SetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_USERDATA,
                        long((LPCREATESTRUCT(lParam))->lpCreateParams));
    }

    wnd = (WinHandle*) (::GetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_USERDATA));

    if (wnd)
        return wnd->WndProc(msg,wParam,lParam);
    else
        return ::DefWindowProc(hwnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
}
```

Since this functions is static , there is no **this** pointer and it works perfectly with WNDCLASSEX, but for some reason it never calls **wnd->WndProc()** and always returns the default window procedure. Need Help. What is wrong? Does anyone know a better approach?

Comment: Have you stepped through it in the debugger?

Comment: Yup.And I coded a message box at the start of **wnd->WndProc()** and that never shows. Then I created a message box at the start of the **else return ::DefWindowProc()** statement and it constantly displayed.

Comment: selbie's answer is likely correct; have you actually inspected the value you're getting from lpCreateParams?

Comment: Definitely take a look to make sure it's the same value you're passing in, and that the value is the correct pointer to the `WinHandle` you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call SetWindowLong when you receive WM_CREATE, not WM_NCCREATE. I don't think lpCreateParams is valid in WM_NCCREATE. That is:

```
if (msg == WM_CREATE)
{
    ::SetWindowLong(hwnd,GWL_USERDATA,
                    long((LPCREATESTRUCT(lParam))->lpCreateParams));
}
```

Comment: Are you certain that the this point is getting passed as lpParam is getting set in CreateWindow?  Have you set a debugger breakpoint on CreateWindow and/or your WndProc to validate anything?

Comment: ALso, SetWindowsLongPtr/GetWindowLongPtr are safer functions to use - required for 64-bit compiles.

Comment: Thanks! It wasn't , Now I have fixed it. I was actually passing **(void*) this** into the CreateWindow function instead of just **this** , maybe that caused some problem. Anyway, it works properly now that I have removed the **(void*)** conversion. Thanks Again! ^_^

Comment: The (void*) cast likely had nothing to do with the issue.  You probably just needed to recompile again.  Glad to help.

Comment: You likely just need to "build clean" to make these mysterious errors go away.

Comment: Plz ignore that comment about SetWindowLongPtr etc. Those are now working with WM_CREATE too.the "build clean" solution often works for some reason, but this time you were right and WM_NCCREATE _was_ the problem. Sorry for my first comment, i'll delete it.